# Find open ports on host from inside a docker container with `docker.sock` mounted

Tags: linux, docker, port, continuous-deployment

I am currently working on enabling review apps in gitlab. In order to do that I need to deploy an app for every merge request/ branch. Which means I need to find open ports where I can deploy to.

Usually this issue would be solved by the answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55913/whats-the-easiest-way-to-find-an-unused-local-port). But as the Gitlab Runner is itself a docker container with `docker.sock` mounted, I can not simply execute a script on the host to find empty ports.

So I am looking for an elegant solution.

I could of course always ssh into the host to execute such a script, but that seems like a very ugly solution.

I wonder whether I can mount anything else into the Runner to allow a script executed within the Runner to find open ports on the host.

Comment: I am thinking that a container which is run with `--network=host` might be able to just execute such a script and get the correct ports.

Comment: Can you launch the container with `docker run -p` with only one port number to let Docker pick the host port itself?  Or `docker run -P` (capital "P") to publish every exposed port on a random open port this way?

Comment: @DavidMaze maybe, but then I would still need to figure out those ports which sounds like a ton of grep/regex and I would have to rewrite the docker-compose files which currently expect environment variables to define the port it should map to (which also makes sense if you want to do it manually or want a specific port)

Answer (score 0):

Please tell me to delete this answer if this does not do what I think it does:

`find_empty_port.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(('', 0))
    print(s.getsockname()[1])
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8

COPY find_empty_port.py find_empty_port.py

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "find_empty_port.py" ]
```

using the command

```sh
docker build -t find_empty_port .
```

lets me use the dockercontainer just like the script:

```sh
docker run --rm --network host find_empty_port
```

which is also possible to do from within a container which has `docker.sock` mounted.